.NET Core published site pointing to dev server wwwroot
I have my dev server and from there I build and deploy a site using a folder target.
Here is my publish profile:
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>C:\temp\stagingPublish</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>my project guid</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
    <Content Update="appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

However, when I copy the contents of C:\temp\stagingPublish to my live server and try to start the site, I get the following error:

DirectoryNotFoundException: E:\Hosting\mysite\presentation\MVC\wwwroot\
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(string root, ExclusionFilters filters)
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(string root)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader+<>c.b__1_0(string contentRoot)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider..ctor(StaticWebAssetManifest manifest, Func<string, IFileProvider> fileProviderFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssetsCore(IWebHostEnvironment environment, Stream manifest)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost+<>c.b__9_0(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder cb)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
BlankSiteCore.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs

Which is a directory only found on my dev server.
What do I need to do to have it look for wwwroot in the hosting environment? I'm hosting on IIS if that's relevant.

Please show your Program.cs.

Sigh...
Clean and rebuild did the trick
